# HTML pattern validation on input elements

Tags: html

Abit annoying to work with since I cannot seem to get this right.

I need to get a pattern that accepts exactly 12 characters containing upper case letters and numbers. Nothing more nor less than 12 characters.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Licence Number.." pattern="[A-Z0-9]+" maxlength="12" minlength="12"  title="Enter Licence number">
```

I am going about this in a wrong way because everytime I am entering 12 characters it is activating the validation message.

Comment: what validation msg does it come up with?

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/ to check what your regular expressions are doing.

Comment: I prefer https://regexr.com for regex validation. It has a "cheatsheet" list which is really useful for constructing expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `minlength` attribute and use the pattern `[A-Z0-9]{12}` instead:

```css
input:invalid {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Licence Number..." pattern="[A-Z0-9]{12}" maxlength="12" title="Enter Licence number">
```

The `minlength` attribute is not needed using the above pattern. The `maxlength` attribute isn't also needed with the above pattern but it stops the input after 12 chars.

At the moment your pattern allows all license numbers with at least one upper case letter or number.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are missing in your regular expression is an exact count. Your regex will match if any input character matches your specification ***at least once***. This means that no matter how long your input is, or how many "illegal" characters there are, if just one uppercase letter or digit is input, the regex will match.

The following will check for exactly 12 of any uppercase letter or digit.

```
[A-Z0-9]{12}
```